# Node ordering in Graph optimization

Tags: optimization, graphs, cplex-python-api

I'm solving a network optimization problem which is modeled as a graph $G=(V,E)$. Solving this problem using **Pulp** and **NetworkX** in Python and ordering the graph's nodes in a certain order (i.e. **(1,2,3,4,5)**) gives a certain optimal solution. However, changing the order of the nodes (i.e.,**(3,4,1,2,5)**) may lead to another optimal solution.
**Is there a metric for nodes that can order the nodes to provide the best optimal solution/s instead of going through the whole possible orders?**

Comment: I see you are still struggling with this issue. I still think the problem should be solved at the root, and not at this stage. To me this looks like a consequence of an ill posed problem. I would suggest investigating from the very beginning and sharing your problem entirely, not just bits here and there. Also the initial context would help. Is this part of a research project ? an industrial project ? fun ?

Comment: Thank you Kuifje for your comment.  Sure it is not for fun. I'm working on a research project.  I have solved the problem to an optimal solution as I mentioned but I was curious regarding the ordering of the nodes since I've noticed it might change the optimal solution. So, I was curious to know if there is an optimal ordering for the nodes. Regarding posting questions and learning from others experience, isn't that what is it all about?

Comment: Yes of course this what this forum is all about, don't get me wrong :) It's just that this question hints that there may be a problem somewhere upstream. If changing the order of the nodes has an influence on the solution, then I would have little confidence in having reached optimality.

Comment: All optimal solutions will have the same objective value (by definition of "optimal"). So what makes one optimal solution the "best" optimal solution?

Comment: Thank you for your comment Kuifje.  @prubin As I understand, each order of the nodes is considered as a different scenario, that is why each order getting a different solution and a different objective value.

Comment: @Amedeo Are you saying that the optimal value obtained using one ordering is different *in objective value* from the optimal solution obtained using another ordering, but that all orderings have the same underlying graph?

Comment: @prubin As I understand, indeed, the objective value changes. The initial thread was [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/is-the-order-of-edges-in-graph-is-changing-the-optimization-result)